# In MVC can I use data annotation to replace default text with an image?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, data-annotations

I am wondering if there is anything built in to MVC (I am using 4 at the moment) that would allow me to change the display from a text field name to an image.

From model:

```
 [Display(Name = "Red")]
        public virtual int? RedManaCost { get; set; }
```

From view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cards.RedManaCost)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cards.RedManaCost, new {style = "width:50px"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cards.RedManaCost)
        </div>
```

This renders the word Red over my textbox. What I would like is an image of the red symbol instead. I know I can hardcode this into my views... I was hoping for a more efficient method. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing built in to MVC that will do this

Comment: Well, if you don't want to "hard code" it into your `Views`, you're probably not going to want to "hard code" it into your `Models` either :) IMHO, once _rendered_ , that "data" is now in the DOM where you can handle things _client-side_ (as needed, and not have to change source if you want to handle things differently at some other point in time).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper, that you pass the `DiplayNameFor` ("Red", "Blue", etc) and inside the helper you do a `Switch` putting the color instead of the label. In my example I'm using a colored `DIV` instead of an image... but you can change that `DIV` with a `IMG` using your icons.

**Something like:**

```
@helper CardColor(string myColor){
    switch(myColor.ToUpper()){
         case "RED":
               <div style="background-color: #FF0000; width: 20px; height:20px;"></div>
               break;
         case "BLUE":
               <div style="background-color: #0000FF; width: 20px; height:20px;"></div>
               break;
}
```

**And you use it like this:**

```
@CardColor(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cards.RedManaCost).ToHtmlString())
```

**Note:** I'm not sure if `DisplayNameFor` was already present in MVC4 but if not... you could create an extension.

Comment: That looks promising. Where would I put the @ helper case code? My project doesn't seem to recognize @ helper anywhere I type it. :(

Comment: At the end of your razor view.